# How can I get golang mysql driver to timeout pings in 2 seconds?

Tags: mysql, go, timeout, connection-timeout

I am having some trouble figuring out how to make a database connection-attempt timeout properly in Go.  I am using some of the examples at [this excellent resource](https://golang.org/src/database/sql/example_test.go) as a base.  I believe I am setting up everything correctly, but my pings just refuse to time out after 2 seconds.  I've extracted the code in question into a sample program as follows.  Note that there is no database running at 172.1.2.3.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql" //MySQL driver
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.Print("Trying to ping database!")

    //Prepare a "context" to execute queries in, this will allow us to use timeouts
    var bgCtx = context.Background()
    var ctx2SecondTimeout, cancelFunc2SecondTimeout = context.WithTimeout(bgCtx, time.Second*2)
    defer cancelFunc2SecondTimeout()

    //Open  database connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:@tcp(172.1.2.3)/testdb?parseTime=true")
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Unable to open db, %s", err.Error())
        return
    }
    log.Print("Successfully called open()")

    //Ping database connection with 2 second timeout
    err = db.PingContext(ctx2SecondTimeout)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Can't ping database server in order to use storage, %s", err.Error())
        return
    }
    log.Print("Successfully pinged database!")
}
```

Running the program should take up to about 2 seconds, but instead it takes 2+ minutes:

```
$ go run lambdatry.go
2018/09/03 16:33:33 Trying to ping database!
2018/09/03 16:33:33 Successfully called open()
2018/09/03 16:35:43 Can't ping database server in order to use storage, dial tcp 172.1.2.3:3306: connect: connection timed out
```

If I change the IP of the "database" (I just picked a random IP so there's no database at this address) the database sometimes times out immediately and sometimes takes a really long time to timeout.

I am running go 1.10.1 on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-options.html Play with `MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT`

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27476 ?

My issue is slightly different, it times out one 1s but not 2s or 3s!
https://media.dev.unee-t.com/2018-09-05/pingcontext.mp4

My source is here: https://media.dev.unee-t.com/2018-09-05/main.go

Comment: Yup!  In fact that's the bug report I made at the same time as this question to let them know about the issue haha.  Once there's a solution there, we should know the solution here as well.  That's good to know about the 1s workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use the following MySQL DSN format to timeout in 2s and it works perfectly fine.

```
user:password@tcp(localhost:80)/dbname?timeout=2s
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't the fault of `PingContext`. tldr skip to the bottom.

`PingContext` supports contexts with timeouts, but in debugging this, it seems the root of the cause is calling `sql.Open()`, or some other call to `sql.Conn()` followed by a call to `PingContext` after. The first two acquire the `db.mu.lock`, which `PingContext` ends up waiting on before it has the chance to use your timeout context:
https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/database/sql/sql.go#L1394

It becomes more clear when using `conn.PingContext` instead of `db.PingContext`, e.g. for a blocked port, this is how timeouts play out:

```golang
db, err := sql.Open(driver, connStr)
if err != nil {
    // This error will not happen
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

// Create a 1 second timeout
ctxBG := context.Background()
ctxConnTimeout, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctxBG, 1*time.Second)
defer cancel()

conn, err := db.Conn(ctxConnTimeout) // Hangs here for 60 seconds, never uses my timeout
if err != nil {
        // This error fires
    log.Fatalln(err)
}

// Never got here
ctxPingTimeout, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctxBG, 1*time.Second)
defer cancel()

err = conn.PingContext(ctxPingTimeout)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
```

So how to pass a timeout to `sql.Open` or `sql.Conn`? It seems this is the only way:

```golang
sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@/dbname?timeout=5s")

sql.Open("postgres", "user=user dbname=dbname connect_timeout=5")

sql.Open("sqlserver", "sqlserver://username:password@host/instance?dial+timeout=5")
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52895312/786389

Answer (score 0):

MySQL DSN format to timeout works perfectly fine.

I just want to point out why the set context timeout of 2s does not take effect, and why the displayed timeout is the number 2 min.

The context does not take effect because in golang's sql/driver, the context used by dial to establish a database connection is not the same context as the context passed to the ping command in your code. The timeout setting of the context used by this dial needs to be set using the parameters in the dsn.

The reason for the 2min timeout is that the setting of the kernel parameter `tcp_syn_retries` used by Linux to establish a tcp connection is estimated to be 6. This will cause tcp to try to establish a connection for up to 127s when the network packet is lost before returning an error.